# Kenyan visa requirements for entry to South Africa

Tags: visas, visa-free-entry, south-africa, kenyan-citizens

Do Kenyans need a visa to travel to South Africa for 3 months as a visitor?

Answer (score 1):

No. A visa waiver for Kenyan nationals was implemented on 1 Jan 2023.

Kenyan nationals can enter South Africa for tourism and business purposes for up to 90 days per annum. Business activities, including attending business meetings or conferences, are allowed but performing paid work activities is not.

Source: http://www.dha.gov.za/index.php/immigration-services/exempt-countries